# SQLite cursor conditional going wrong -- second pair of eyes needed

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So here's my problem -- the code should be simple, yet this isn't working, and I'm not sure why. Below is the code I've set up for a button called NEXT which the user hits after they're done filling in the date and exercise information. If the date entered is already in the database, they should be alerted with a Toast message, and not allowed to proceed to the next page. However, what's happening is that the DB query for the entered date is evidently failing, or the conditional I've set up is somehow blocking execution, or I'm doing something wrong with the Cursor.

Note the conditional in principal question -- if (date_matches.getCount() > 0 && date_matches != null){ //tell user to enter a new date or modify the old one in MODIFY tab}

I've got it right now with an &&, and this results in both existing and non-existing dates to proceed to the next Activity. If I change it to ||, execution never reaches the 'else' block, even if the date does not already exist in the database.

Any shove in the right direction would be appreciated on this pesky little issue!

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){

            String date = date_entry.getText().toString();              
            String exercise = date_entry.getText().toString(); //this is not required -- can modify day to add later

            //If date field left empty but NEXT button pressed, issue a toast message telling user to enter one
            if (date == null || date.length() == 0){
                CharSequence message = "No date given. Please enter one before pressing NEXT";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
                toast.show();}

            //If exercise left empty but NEXT button pressed, will just fill exercise with 'none', which can be 
            //later modified if user exercises after they create their new date
            if (exercise == null || exercise.length() == 0){
                exercise = "None";
            }

            String query = "SELECT * FROM food_entries WHERE date = "+date;

            Cursor date_matches = mDbHelper.getData(query);

            //There is a problem with this conditional -- even when there should be no matching rows for
            //a new date, this is coming up with some sort of result and letting it pass
            if (date_matches.getCount() > 0 && date_matches != null){
                //Matching date in food_entries, meaning foods for that date already inputted
                CharSequence message = "Information for "+date+" already exists. Add/modify in MODIFY tab";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);}

            else{
                //No matching dates; can add new date
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddFoodsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("date_key", date);
                intent.putExtra("exercise_key", exercise);
                    startActivity(intent);} 

            }});
```

Comment: You may need to post your code for your `mDbHelper` class. So we can see what `getData()` does exactly.

Comment: Aha! The getdata() does indeed call raw query. Will update code when I get back and see if that doesn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ack, so here was the fix:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM food_entries WHERE date = '"+date+"'";
```

Yes, that's right. All that grief because of a missing set of single quotes. What tipped me off was when I was trying to look at the cursor results with `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"))`. There was an error saying that an int was found but a String required -- then I knew something was up with the query itself, and not my conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Your `getData` function is likely to call `query` or `rawQuery`.
These functions never return `null`; when they find nothing, they return a valid cursor with zero items.
(Only content providers might return `null` instead of an empty cursor.)

Just drop the `date_matches != null` check.

Comment: I agree with this statement but still doesn't answer the question. The check is pointless but should not stop the condition from being true.

Comment: @KieronPapps `anything || date_matches != null` is always true.